# Why do the two functions give different results?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I defined two functions using `RcppArmadillo` package and save them into the file `cxxFuns.cpp`. The only difference between `f01` and `f02` is the positions of `V(0, 0)`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat f01 (arma::mat x) {
    unsigned int p0 = x.n_cols ;
    unsigned int iR = 0, iC = 0 ;
    arma::mat V(3, 3) ; V.fill(NA_REAL) ;
    for (iR = 0; iR < p0; iR++) { 
        V(0, 0) = arma::sum(x.col(iR) % x.col(iR)) ;
        for (iC = iR+1; iC < p0; iC++) {
            ;
        }
    }
    
    return V ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat f02 (arma::mat x) {
    unsigned int p0 = x.n_cols ;
    unsigned int iR = 0, iC = 0 ;
    arma::mat V(3, 3) ; V.fill(NA_REAL) ;
    for (iR = 0; iR < p0; iR++) { 
        for (iC = iR+1; iC < p0; iC++) {
            V(0, 0) = arma::sum(x.col(iR) % x.col(iR)) ;
        }
    }
    
    return V ;
}
```

As I understand, the function `f01` and `f02` should give identical results. However, the testing does not show the expected results.

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(2020)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('cxxFuns.cpp')
x <- matrix(rnorm(100*10), 10)
(egg01 <- f01(x))
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 12.78607   NA   NA
[2,]       NA   NA   NA
[3,]       NA   NA   NA

(egg02 <- f02(x))
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 14.80855   NA   NA
[2,]       NA   NA   NA
[3,]       NA   NA   NA
```

What happened?

Comment: please do not repost questions. As you improved the original it can be reopened now, but we don't need the same question twice

Comment: well... or just delete the old one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last execution in the first block is when `iR = p0-1`.

The last execution in the second block is when `iC=p0-1`.
Since `iC` starts as `iR+1`, your last execution is for `iR=p0-2`.

Printing the value of `iR` before computing `V(0,0)` or running under a debugger should have immediately made this clear.